# Android - Can I change the reference of a TextView with a button?

Tags: java, android

I have this code

```
final String[] instructionsStrings  = { "instruction 1",
                                                "instruction 2",
                                                "instruction 3",
                                                "instruction 4"};
final int[] instructionIndex = {0};
ImageButton imageButtonNext = findViewById(R.id.imageButtonNext);
imageButtonNext.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick(View view) {
          if (instructionIndex[0] < 3){
              instructionIndex[0]++;
              instructions.setText(instructionsStrings[instructionIndex[0]]);
          }
      }
});
```

which changes a text view within an array, but i also have a strings.xml file which I have this strings

```
<string name="instructions_1">instruction 1</string>
<string name="instructions_2">instruction 2</string>
<string name="instructions_3">instruction 3</string>
<string name="instructions_4">instruction 4</string>
```

can I instead of changing the text value change the reference to the strings.xml file?

Comment: I recommend you should declare instructions by string-array instead of string in xml, in your code instructionsStrings = getResource().getStringArrays()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should initialize `instructionsStrings()` with `String resources`.

Your final code:

```
final String[] instructionsStrings  = { getString(R.string.instruction_1),
                                           getString(R.string.instruction_2),
                                           getString(R.string.instruction_3),
                                           getString(R.string.instruction_4)};
```

You can read more detailed information in the [documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/string-resource)